# Annotations for Google Cloud Monitoring charts

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I'd like to add annotations to Google Cloud Monitoring charts in the same manner that I can for Grafana charts.  Is that possible?

Comment: Upon further checking, this feature is not yet supported. You may submit your query as a Feature Request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). However, for feature requests there is no guarantee of any time frame for updates or that the requested feature will be implemented.